# Calculate the amount using sql case on free product

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, business-intelligence, msbi

I have a sales table which contains (product code, quantity, unitprice...) and I want to calculate the amount for each product code but I have some free product in with I want to have the amount to be 0

How can I do it with SQL?

This is the idea of what I'm expecting

```sql
CASE
    WHEN freegoodline = 0 THEN
        AMOUNT = SUM(B.QUANTITYB.UNITPRICEB.VAT1RATE) OVER(partition by B.PRODUCT_CODE, B.sinvoice_code)
    ELSE
        AMOUNT = 0
END
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: How have you tried to do it? Can you show us your effort?

Comment: If the product is "free" what is the unit price?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` expression to do *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT productcode, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN productcode = 'free' THEN 0 ELSE quatity * unitprice  END) AS Amount
FROM sales s
GROUP BY productcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if the product is free, then the unit price will be zero or `NULL`.  If that is the case, you simply need:

```
sum(quantity * unitprice)
```

No conditional logic is needed.